# Some questions about complexification of a real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Could you tell me how to prove that if $f:U \rightarrow U$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear, then:

1) $U^{\mathbb{C}}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (should I check all eight conditions for a vector space?)

2) $f^{\mathbb{C}}: U^{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow U^{\mathbb{C}}$ is the only $\mathbb{C}$ - linear mapping such that $f^{\mathbb{C}}|_U = f$

$U^{\mathbb{C}} = U \times U$ - it's a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$

$(a,b) + (c,d) = (a+c, b+d)$

$(a+bi)(c,d) = (ac-bd, ad+bc)$

$f^{\mathbb{C}}(a+ib) = f(a) + if(b)$

Comment: How do you define $U^{\mathbb C}$? In 1) do you mean "... over $\mathbb C$"?

Comment: Do you define $U^{\mathbb C}:=U\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C$?

Comment: I've added more information to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1): As you know that $U^{\mathbb C}$ is a $\mathbb C$-vector space, think if restriction of the multiplication $\mathbb C \times U^{\mathbb C} \to U^{\mathbb C}$ to $\mathbb R\times U^{\mathbb C}$ can violate any condition.

For 2): Suppose $\def\C{\mathbb C}$$f^\C\colon U^\C \to U^\C$ if $\C$-linear with $f^\C|_U = f$, then we have for $x,y \in U$:
\begin{align*}
  f^\C(x,y) &= f^\C\bigl((x,0) + i\cdot(y,0)\bigr)\\
            &= f^\C(x,0) + if^\C(y,0)\\
            &= \bigl(f(x),0\bigr)+i\cdot \bigl(f(y),0\bigr)\\
            &= \bigl(f(x), f(y)\bigr)
\end{align*}
so there is at most one $\C$-linear extension of $f$, to prove existence, show that $f^\C(x,y) :=\bigl(f(x), f(y)\bigr)$ is $\C$-linear.